# Using an ItemRenderer to output filenames from a path

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I am pretty new to actionscript, I am receiving a XML list of file paths. I need to extract the file name from this so I set up a itemRenderer but I dont get anything for the name. I have added a break point and my fileName does contain the correct filename, but it is never shown in the view. What am I doing wrong?

View Code:

```
<s:SkinnableContainer width="100%">
    <s:DataGroup itemRenderer="modules.custFiles.renderers.CustFileItemRenderer" dataProvider="{custFiles}" width="100%">
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout gap="0"/>
        </s:layout>
    </s:DataGroup>
</s:SkinnableContainer>
```

Renderer Code:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    var node:XML = value as XML;
    _link = node.toString();
    var filename:RegExp = /[^\/\/]*$/ig;
    filename.text = _link.match(filename);

    super.data = value;
}
```

XML:

```
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://mysite.com/srv">
<string>
http://mysite.com/files/custFiles/custfile-1.pdf
</string>
<string>
http://mysite.com/files/custFiles/custfile-2.pdf
</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

Comment: It looks like you get the 'filename.text' but you don't assign it to 'super.data'.

Comment: @ethrbunny isnt that the line `super.data = value;`?

Comment: That's the object that gets passed in. You parse out the filename using a regex - but what are you doing with it? Also - it looks like you use 'filename' as both the regex and the result.

Comment: Thanks! Well how do I correctly assign it to the correct `super.data`?

Comment: How about 'super.data = _link.match(filename);'? --> note that 'match' returns an array. Is that what you want? Perhaps 'search()' instead?

Comment: @ethrbunny Please post this as an answer and I will accept it so you can get credit for it. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line in your 'set data' function to:

> super.data = _link.match(filename);

You aren't setting the correct value in the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you don't need a custom renderer. Just transform the data into an IList of String:

```
function toListOfString(xml:XML):IList {
  if (!xml) return new ArrayCollection();

  const children:XMLList = xml.children(),
        source:Array = [];

  for each(var child:XML in children) source.push(child.text())

  return new ArrayCollection(source);
}
```

Get the result and assign the result of the method to a list. This will help you to get started and show you as well to separate the single problems that come with Flex development.

Why am i proposing that way? XML/XMLList instances are not the best match for working with data in Flex. DataBinding is not supported by these classes, so you will move on to classes the more complex the app gets anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some text component like `Label` with name `filename` in your renderer, but then you declare local variable with name `filename` of type `RegExp`.

And you are not lucky now - `RegExp` is `dynamic` class, that means your

`filename.text = _link.match(filename);`

does not generate an error. But it should.
Try to rename your local variable to something like `fileNameRegExp`.

By the way, @ethrbunny  has already mentioned that fact, so I guess you shall give 'accept' to @ethrbunny.